# Implementing TinyMCE and JQuery in laravel 4.1?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-4, tinymce, assets

I want to use TinyMCE and JQuery in my laravel 4.1 application but i don't know where to store the files. I know you can use assets to include JavaScript, but there is also a vendor folder. So how can i do this the right way?

Greetings,

Jan

Answer (score 0):

You can place in the package folder located inside public one folder for TinyMCE and inside public create a folder called js for instance where you can put jquery

```
/public
  ../packages/TinyMCE
  ../js/jquery.js
  ../js/jquery.min.js
```

The packages folder is normally used for external libraries.

Comment: But isn't the package directory supposed for real Laravel packages with a package structure?